# Excel help: Calculate the weighted average of the last 4 elements in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose that you have a column that starts to get bigger and bigger. And all you want to do is to calculate the weighted average value of the last n elements in the column. I already know how to calculate the average value of the last 4 values however I don't know to combine it with the weighted factors.
This is the formula I use to calculate the average:

```
AVERAGE(OFFSET(A1,COUNT(A2:A50),0,-4))
```

This gives a value. Maybe I should have a vector of the values and then multiplicate it with the weight factors.

An algorithm as:

1. Find the last values
2. Create a vector of them
3. Multipli the vector with the weight factor vector,
4. Sum the resutls.

Comment: Does **A1** contain a *Header* ??

Comment: "Maybe I should have a vector of the values and then multiplicate it with the weight factors" - did you try that?  Where are the weights?

Answer (score 0):

If your weights are in ColB and first row is a (non-numeric) header

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(A1,COUNT(A:A)-3,0,4,1) * OFFSET(B1,COUNT(A:A)-3,0,4,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate weighted average in Excel, you might use the standard functions `Sumproduct()` and `Sum()` (the latter for dividing by the sum of the weights), this is quite well shown in [this URL here](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/weighted-average.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,COUNT(A2:A50),0,-4)*OFFSET(B1,COUNT(A2:A50),0,-4))/SUM(OFFSET(B1,COUNT(A2:A50),0,-4))
```

Here `B1` is the cell that has the first element of the array of weights; change both instances of `B1` in this formula as needed.